# PHP catch errores de include (y amigos)

Tags: php, try-catch

Tengo el siguiente código donde intento atrapar los errores de `include`, `require`, `include_once`, `require_once`. Sin embargo no lo consigo.

```
try {
    require("config.php");
} catch(Error $e) {
    throw new Exception("No se pudo incluir el archivo configuración", 103);
    die();
}
```

He leído aquí y allí y he probado diferentes alternativas y lo único que obtengo son `warnings` y `fatal errors`.
Graceas!

Comment: Pregunta retórica: ¿Deberíamos resolver en código los problemas de publicación?

Comment: @Sal, cómo? no entendí...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include` y `require` no lanzan excepciones. De hecho, es un error de diseño tener que capturar esa posibilidad. Lo que puedes hacer es usar `file_exists()` para verificar previamente si la ruta existe y si no, provocar la excepción con `throw`.

Por otro lado, estás usando la clase `Exception` para generar la instancia o el objeto de error, entonces en `catch` debes usar la misma clase. Ver [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php).

```php
try {
    if(file_exists('config.php')) {
        require_once 'config.php'; // <-- require_once por si ya fue incluido
    } else {
        throw new Exception("No se pudo incluir el archivo configuración", 103);
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: "es un error de diseño tener que capturar esa posibilidad"... error mío o error de php?